# CSS3 selectors are not working to hide the password reveal icon in IE 11

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to hide the password reveal icon using CCS selector as shown below.

```
input::-ms-reveal{
display: none;                      
}
```

**My development environment:**
.Net Framework: .Net 4.5.1, 
Visual Studio 2010, 
IIS 7.5

I use IE11, and when checked for compatibility in jsFiddle, it works and hides the password reveal icon.

http://jsfiddle.net/evildonald/jLuF5/

Why it is not working in my website (local & host). Any ideas as solution is appreciated..

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 10 only supports hiding password reveal icon using CSS

```
input::-ms-clear, input::-ms-reveal {
 display: none;
 }
```

For IE 11, I found solution [here](http://seckb.yehg.net/2013/04/microsoft-internet-explorer-10-client.html) , using javascript. Hope this help others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
input::-ms-clear, input::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}
```

---

- `::-ms-clear` represents a button (the "clear button") at the edge of a text  which clears away the current value of the `<input>` element
- `::-ms-reveal` applies one or more styles to the password reveal button of an `<input> type=password` control

Comment: Lalji, I tried with your suggestion, but still I can see the Password reveal icon. I noticed the below code when I try to see the CSS code in Developer tool(F12 on my IE webpage) 
<STYLE type=text/css>INPUT:unknown {
 DISPLAY: none
}
INPUT:unknown {
 DISPLAY: none
}
</STYLE>