# How do you getComputedStyle() for the ::-ms-reveal pseudoelement?

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge

Edge browser has a password reveal button for password inputs on by default. To hide this is straightforward: we just target the `::-ms-reveal` pseudoelement and add a property of `display: none` or set the widths and heights to 0.

For testing purposes, I'm trying to get the computed style of the `input::-ms-reveal` element and assert that it has the expected `display: none` style, but it always logs the property to be `inline-block` (seems to be grabbing the input element's display value).  How do I get the pseudoelement's display value?

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('pass'), '::-ms-reveal'); // should grab pseudoelement styles, but doesn't work as expected.
```

See the associated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ck19h4f5/2/

It seems like some pseudoelements work as expected and you can see their computed styles, but I'm unable to get the pseudoelement `::-ms-reveal` to compute styles correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's due to `::-ms-reveal` is not compatible with modern browsers. You can refer to [this doc](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Archive/Web/CSS/::-ms-reveal). It shows that `::-ms-reveal` is *historically supported in Internet Explorer and Edge before version 79*. I test the code in Edge **IE mode** and it can get `::-ms-reveal` computed styles correctly:

[image]

**Update:**

I checked the doc again and found that it's from a backup site. The MDN site now removes the doc about `::-ms-reveal`. You can check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Microsoft_Extensions#pseudo-elements).

Actually, I think using `::-ms-reveal` is still the most common way to remove the password reveal icon for now. But it indeed has compatibility issue with `getComputedStyle()` in modern browsers. I searched and found a JavaScript way to hide the password reveal icon. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629190/css3-selectors-are-not-working-to-hide-the-password-reveal-icon-in-ie-11/39203705#39203705). I test the code in the link and it works in Edge.

Comment: Great find! If we're not using `::-ms-reveal` is there any other way to remove that password reveal icon?

Comment: Hi @htoor please check my updated answer. You can have a try with the JavaScript way to hide the password reveal icon. For the issue that getting `::-ms-reveal` computed styles incorrectly, I suggest that you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge.